# SelectOutput block not triggering when condition is true

Tags: anylogic

I have this model, which is basically processing orders until a disruption event occurs. When this event occurs, the variable *fail* turns True and the *Output select block* should become *true* and exit to *Repairing*, but it's not happening. Any reasons you might think that's happening?

[Model print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PZuG.png)

Comment: Perhaps obvious to you but this is only 'not working' if agents don't route correctly once they leave the Queue. Your screenshot may be 'correct' in that `fail` was set to `true` after the 2 agents that left the Queue did so. The problem is only definite if `fail` stays `true` and agents subsequently leaving the Queue take the bottom (false) exit of the SelectOutput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typical reason would be that you are defining your failure condition in the "on exit" instead of the "on at exit" on your queue block

Comment: Actually, the failure occurs at an absolute time on the disruptionEvent (event block). All it does is set the variable fail=true

Comment: well, then also please share a screen of the SelectOutput code you are using :)

Comment: it just has the variable fail. I've also tried fail==true

Comment: i don't believe you @DanieldeSousaRibeiro... you better share a screen shot of that selectOutput

Comment: that was the truth aha but I've moved on with another solution that worked just fine. Thank you for your time!